# Square integral symbol

Tags: symbols, integral

How can I write a square version of the integral sign? I'm looking for something that has the same height as a regular integral sign and looks like this:

[image]

Note that this symbol is not found by Detexify and does not appear to be in the [comprehensive list of symbols](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always build your own symbol. (If you want such integrals also to show up as subscripts, you need to add the corresponding code to the last options of `\mathchoice`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\SquareInt}{\mathchoice{\tikz[baseline=0.55em]{%
\draw[line width=0.08em] (-0.2em,0em) 
|- (0,-0.2em) -- (0,1.9em) -| (0.2em,1.7em);}}{\tikz[baseline=0.35em]{%
\draw[line width=0.06em] (-0.2em,0em) 
|- (0,-0.2em) -- (0,1.2em) -| (0.2em,1em);}}{}{}}
\begin{document}
\[ \SquareInt\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\quad\text{vs.}\quad 
\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\]
$\SquareInt\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\quad\text{vs.}\quad 
\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: TikZ is great !

Answer (score 4):

You can design your own using `\rule`s. This solution measures the height and depth of the integral to ensure exact size.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc} % needed to add lengths 
\usepackage{amsmath} % needed for \DeclareMathOperator

\newlength{\hght}
\newlength{\dpth}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sqrint}{\mathchoice%
{\settoheight{\hght}{$\displaystyle{\int}$}\settodepth{\dpth}{$\displaystyle{\int}$}% measures \int
    \rule[-\dpth]{.2ex}{.5ex}% lower vert
    \rule[-\dpth]{.12em}{.2ex}% lower hor
    \rule[-\dpth]{.2ex}{\hght+\dpth}% main vert
    \rule[\hght-.2ex]{.12em}{.2ex}% upper hor
    \rule[\hght-.5ex]{.2ex}{.5ex}}% upper vert
{\settoheight{\hght}{$\int$}\settodepth{\dpth}{$\int$}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.15ex}{.4ex}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.1em}{.15ex}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.15ex}{\hght+\dpth}%
    \rule[\hght-.15ex]{.1em}{.15ex}%
    \rule[\hght-.4ex]{.15ex}{.4ex}}%
{\settoheight{\hght}{$\scriptstyle{\int}$}\settodepth{\dpth}{$\scriptstyle{\int}$}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.1ex}{.3ex}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.08em}{.1ex}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.1ex}{\hght+\dpth}%
    \rule[\hght-.1ex]{.08em}{.1ex}%
    \rule[\hght-.3ex]{.1ex}{.3ex}}%
{}}

\begin{document}

Inline square integral: $\int_0^1\sqrint_0^1$, subscripted: $A_{\int_0^1\sqrint_0^1}$, or a displayed version:
\[
\int_0^1\sqrint_0^1
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that I have not added the code for a scriptscript version. You can adjust the lengths and thicknesses as you wish.